# MonoGame 3.5 solution build error when try to compile code

Tags: c#, compilation, monogame, solution

When i compile the code the solution does not build, this is default code result. I am using vs 2013 professional edition.

[image: Screenshot showing ErrorCode -1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the content pipeline for your project. It seems like you have some content that is broken. I've seen this happen with spritefonts in the past.